# build and deploy Docker image on linux in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: docker, .net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab, dockerfile

I have a requirement in which I have to create a docker image for a .NET Core 3.1 app. For that I have this docker file. Can anyone help me creating `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for creating docker image and deploy it to docker on Linux?

*Docker File*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./Service/ .
RUN dotnet restore "Service/Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Hervice"
RUN dotnet build "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation on `.gitlab-ci.yaml` files? Have you tried out [the step by step guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_from_scratch.html)? Do you have anything working? Also, suppose you have gitlab building your docker container. Where are you going to deploy it to? Gitlab itself wont run your containers; it will only build them.

Comment: Here is sample GitLab CI script for building docker image and pushing to registry - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-hub-integrations/blob/master/GitLab/standard-docker-registry/.gitlab-ci.yml. Not that it also discusses integration with the project I'm working on - Reliza Hub - more info here https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870.

Also, here you can find sample pipeline for deployment via GitLab - https://gitlab.com/taleodor/sample-helm-cd